# remote mkdir denied until granted domain admin permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, mkdir

I'm trying to automate homedir folder creation for my AD users, using a service account for the whole automation and PowerShell. I gave my SA full control on the remote root folder, however I get this error:

```
mkdir $homedirFullpath
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (*********************:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Of course, as soon as I give domain admin permissions to my service account, no error, the folder is created. Obviously, the goal here is to set my service account with the least amount of privileges to do that simple task.

Anyone know the requirements?

Comment: Just tried from the remote srv with the SA on a ISE window, no error! So it is some remote settings/permissions that I don't see.

Comment: you may be seeing the `double hop problem`. since you didn't give full details on how the code is being run, i can't be sure of that. [*grin*]

Comment: Yesterday I was searching this way... but, why as soon as I add my service account to domain admins groupe there is no error ?

Comment: Ideally i must run a script from server A to create the folder on server B. I write my code on ISE that I opened with the service account and I'm logged to server A with my personal admin account wihich is domain admin if it matters.

Comment: [1] as mentioned, i don't see enuf detail to be certain that it is a double hop glitch. the problem usually happens when you run a script from A to B and try to access something from B ... and therefor lack the full permission token that you had going from A to B. [2] running things from inside the ISE can be ... strange. it DOES NOT clear variables since you are running everything in one session. when you use the console, you normally start a new console with each run ... and therefor use a new session with each run.

Comment: To be honest I gave up and my service account is now domain admin, thank you for your time anyway. :)

Comment: real life trumps all ... and you got it working as needed. good! [*grin*]